# Error while consuming calling REST API with React app

Tags: java, reactjs, api, rest

I have a react app running on localhost:3000 and I try to consume calling REST API by java ee backend rest server, running on localhost:8080. I have enabled CORS on header.

I tried to make a form submit post request on my component.

```
fetchApi = () => {

    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/test/api/rest/Service/checkCode';

    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization');
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ' GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var myInit = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            code: '15465',
            name: 'Jack',
        })
    };

    fetch(url, myInit)

        .then(function(response) {

            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            else{
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }


        }).then(function(data){

        console.log(data);
        this.setState({items: data});

    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    })
};
```

I have errors in line:

```
 fetch(url, myInit):
```

> OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/test/api/rest/Service/checkCode 500 (Erreur Interne de Servlet)

And CORS Error:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/test/api/rest/Service/checkCode. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'ttp://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: At Java side you to enable the cors

Comment: Its not exactly a solution but to test if the problem is on CORS you can set fetch option `mode: 'no-cors'` and disable CORS.

Comment: Remove all of the `myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow…')` stuff from your request code. Those are all *response* headers for servers to send back. Adding them to requests in your client code is just going to break things.

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 500* indicates some server-side failure occurs when that java server receives an OPTIONS request. You probably want to look through server logs on the server side to see what messages are logged there when that 500 internal server failure occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I removed all of the myHeader.append('Access-Control-Allow...') and I put 'no-cors' mode now I only have POST localhost:8080/test/api/rest/Service/checkCode 500 (Erreur Interne de Servlet) and on console.log "network response was not ok". Yep I ll try to look server logs

Comment: Even though the post is late (and there was no accepted answer), I wanted to highlight this point from scalability point of view. Instead of enabling CORS from client side (which is risky as well), better introduce a light weight Nodejs layer that will handle the cors part before making downstream request. This will also help in aggregating data from multiple services keeping the client agnostic of business logic.

Answer (score 0):

this is a backend issue not a frontend you should allow the CORS from the backend and this is depend on the technology that used in the backend
i used spring boot in my backend so by adding this code to the security configuration will solve it

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```